# Error Deserializing Xml to Object - {<string xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected.}

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization, xmldocument

I have problem when try to deserializing XML to object, 
I got on error message

```
"There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."
```

With innerException :

```
"<string xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected."
```

I have try solution in these link : 
[Error Deserializing Xml to Object - xmlns='' was not expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884383/error-deserializing-xml-to-object-xmlns-was-not-expected), [xmlns=''> was not expected. - There is an error in XML document (2, 2) while DeserializeXml to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751408/xmlns-was-not-expected-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-2-2-while-des)

but still not resolve my problem..

Here is my code:

```
    bulk_response result = ConvertXMLString.convertXMLStringToObject<bulk_response>(response);
```

here is my Deserializing  code :

```
public static T convertXMLStringToObject<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
                {
                    return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and here is my class:

```
  public class bulk_response
    {
        public string status_code { get; set; }
        public string status_text { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    }
```

what is the issue i couldn't find ?

Update :
This is the xml i get from http post response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<bulk_response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <status_code>hansen</status_code>
  <status_text>angie</status_text>
  <transaction_id>ini testing aja</transaction_id>
</bulk_response></string>
```

and this is how i passing data via http post and get the response :

```
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
// add the parameters as key valued pairs making
// sure they are URL encoded where needed
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] postData = encoding.GetBytes(param);
httpReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpReq.Method = "POST";
httpReq.ContentLength = postData.Length;
// convert the request to a steeam object and send it on its way
Stream ReqStrm = httpReq.GetRequestStream();
ReqStrm.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
ReqStrm.Close();
// get the response from the web server and
// read it all back into a string variable
HttpWebResponse httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader respStrm = new StreamReader(
httpResp.GetResponseStream());
string result = respStrm.ReadToEnd();
httpResp.Close();
respStrm.Close();

return result;
```

Comment: What does your XML document look like?

Comment: This is the xml i get from http post response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<bulk_response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <status_code>hansen</status_code>
  <status_text>angie<status_text>
  <transaction_id>ini testing aja&lt;/transaction_id>
</bulk_response></string>

Comment: Please do not add details in the comments, but **edit** your question.

Comment: ok... wait a minute

Comment: @PaulKertscher : done, i have add detail of xml in my question...

Comment: That XML is invalid.  Upload it to http://www.xmlvalidation.com and you will see the error `2: 42 The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.`  It looks like somebody tried to embed an XML string inside an outer XML document without either properly escaping it or properly removing the inner XML declaration.

Comment: It looks like the real issue is the unicode encoding : encoding="utf-16".  Somebody attempted to fix this issue by adding a second xml identification with encoding="utf-8" which will not work.  The Net library does not recognize utf-16,  So my normal recommendation is to skip the identification line by using ReadLine().  See my response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658511/how-to-change-the-format-of-all-dates-in-xml/45658738#comment78275697_45658738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you serialize your XML? It looks pretty messed up.

1. The additional `<?xml ...` after the `<string>` tag looks quite strange to me. I have never seen this. Is this valid XML?
2. When you deserialze an object from XML, the serializer expectes the root node to be named like the class. This is what `<string> was not expected.` means - it'd expect a `bulk_response`-tag instead
3. The closing-tag of `status_text` is no closing-tag, should be `<status_text>angie</status_text>`
4. Having `xmlns` definitions on different levels is also uncommon (if it's legal XML at all) - but I do not see why you need them at all, you could just leave them

Having said that, after simplifying your XML to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bulk_response>
  <status_code>hansen</status_code>
  <status_text>angie</status_text>
  <transaction_id>ini testing aja</transaction_id>
</bulk_response>
```

your code works like a charm. The issue does not seem to be the deserializing code, but the serializing code on the server side.

Comment: about closing tag, that is my typo when i update my question.. hmm i see i see...

Comment: My code when i got the http post response is correct??